# Why is my washing machine dripping water?

Tags: water, washing-machine

Moved in a new house and got a new washing machine as well.

When the water is pumped down, its dripping. I also have the dripping on camera (see first 5s: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFfGW1wpXao):

[image]

The waste pipe has a little edge cut out. Is this normal or perhaps the cause of the dripping?  If so, how do you replace this?

[image]

This is the connector module which has a trunk. I pulled it tight with my hand. When I saw it was dripping, I used a pipe wrench to pull it as tight as possible, but still dripping.

[image]

Any thoughts?

https://www.frag-mutti.de/waschmaschinenablauf-undicht-woran-kann-es-liegen-a57008/

Comment: A tip for future reference: Plastic plumbing nuts like this one are _designed_ to be only hand tight. If they're dripping at hand tight, they shouldn't be turned by a tool more than about 1/8 of an additional turn. If it's still dripping after that, something is wrong, and it's not that the nut is too loose.

Answer (score 5):

The [page you linked](https://www.frag-mutti.de/waschmaschinenablauf-undicht-woran-kann-es-liegen-a57008/) tells the story. The fitting on the wall is designed to accept a internal O-ring seal, not an end-washer seal. The elbow on your drain hose is incorrect. You need one that slips inside the black nipple, past the notched area. The notch is presumably a key which will hold position on the elbow as you tighten its nut.

This type of seal requires very little nut tension to retain--the nut mostly keeps it from falling out. Don't use tools, or use them very gently.

[image]

I would not try to seal things at the threads. That leaves the nut-to-elbow connection unsealed and it will probably fail. If you put the black washer *outside* the integrated flange washer, maybe it would work.

I also wouldn't cut off the end of the nipple until you exhaust your other options. If you do, you'll need a nice square, flat cut. Be sure the washer size is suitable first. The reason the internal seal is used is to eliminate alignment problems.

Comment: Oh.. I thought I already aligned with that article, because my connector module had a trunk. But now I understand, the internal ring is what matters. And yes, I also read that one should not use tools to seal the threads, but I tried because it was dripping.  I have now ordered the one on the right side and I will let you know in a week if it worked :)

Comment: So I went to multiple building supplies stores, and they all did not hat that item. I found it online and ordered it https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B006CKU9W6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 - it fits on the pipe but its too tiny for the hose. Do you have an idea where I could buy the correct tool? The service people from building supply store all advised me to cut the pipe off.

Comment: Sorry, no. I've never used that type before. I'd be cutting the pipe off now. :)

Answer (score 1):

The bottom picture of the washer hose looks like there is a rubber seal on the fitting which fits against the end of the wall pipe. The notch in the wall pipe would compromise the seal. You might be able to get a plumber or skilled handyman to mill the end of the wall pipe back so the notch is gone. Otherwise replacement of the wall pipe would be required.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was suspecting, the fitting fits agains the end and then there is this gap below.

Comment: I assume that the notch is a keying mechanism. I wouldn't just grind away until I understood its intended purpose.

Comment: Good point @Isherwood! Could be the washer fitting isn't correct for the pipe either.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove that black threaded pipe by turning the white collar counterclockwise. The notch in the end of it is causing water to get out and leak through the threads. The easiest fix would be to get some Teflon tape and wrap it around the black threads and then screw your fitting on to it. This will stop the water from leaking through the threads. If you're real handy and have a rotary tool with a cutoff wheel, cut off the piece with the notch in it so you have a smooth surface going up against the black washer on you connecting fitting.

Comment: The threads are not where this will leak. Water would escape through the nut bore.

Comment: @isherwood  The OP's picture shows the leak right at the thread line. The nut bore is similar to a plastic drain tail piece going into a trap... no washer, just plastic against plastic and no leak. I do like the internal "o" ring fitting.+1

Comment: That may be where it _is_ leaking. I'm saying that's not where it _will_ leak.